# How to assert a mocked object in a list

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, hamcrest

I have a Junit test as below:

```
ClassA a1 = mock(ClassA.class);
ClassB b1 = new B("1", "abcd1");
testClass.addToMap(b1, a1); //add date to map1
ClassA a2 = mock(ClassA.class);
ClassB b2 = new B("2", "abcd2");
testClass.addToMap(b2, a2); //add date to map1
testClass.dropFromMap(); //this will remove the object from map1 and add the ClassA details to a set(set1)
```

Now the question is that how to verify that the `set1` contains both the mocked `objects(a1, a2)`. Something like below:

```
assertTrue(testClass.set1.contains(a1));
assertTrue(testClass.set1.contains(a2));
```

Unable to use `ArgumentCaptor` as I should provide a proper `b1` object while adding to map.

Comment: I'd say we need some information on the class of `testClass` (which I assume is an instance of said class due to it's naming). What is `set1`? How are elements added? What do `ClassA`'s `equals()` and `hashCode()` look like? What does `mock()` do, i.e. how does it generate an instance of the class?

Comment: Is `testClass.set1` private and is not accessible from test class?

Comment: show the dropFromMap method internals

Comment: the set1 is not a method it is just a protected variable set. This set is getting populated when we call testClass.dropFromMap();

Comment: Just a suspect but is the set1 a set of B objects i.e. Set<B.class>? Can you also tell what kind of objects does the set1 holds ? Are you checking set1.contains(a1), where the set1 is a set of <B> ?

Comment: dropFromMap {
    set1.add(a1);
    set1.add(a2);
    map1.remove(b1);
    map1.remove(b2);
}

Comment: set1 is a set of ClassA object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify that in a single line/statement I would go for the Hamcrest matchers:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

...

testClass.dropFromMap();
assertThat(testClass.set1, containsInAnyOrder(a1, a2));
```

This will make sure that only and exactly these two are in the set.

Comment: This is really worked, thank you :).
But why assertTrue(testClass.set1.contains(a1)); is not worked where i can see both the object (the object which i mocked and object available in the set) has same hashcode.
Mock for ClassB, hashCode: 877612522